# Sockaddr union and getaddrinfo()

Tags: c++, getaddrinfo, sockaddr-in

I'm writing a UDP socket program which is provided an address from the command line.

To make sending and writing easier, I'm using getaddrinfo to convert the address to a sockaddr struct: either sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6. Now I understand that I should use a union of sockaddrs:

```
typedef union address
{
    struct sockaddr s;
    struct sockaddr_in s4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 s6;
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;
} address_t;
```

As I understand they can't be pointers to avoid hiding strict aliasing problems. I'm having trouble seamlessly putting the information from getaddrinfo's addrinfo into this address_t:

```
struct addrinfo hint, *serv = NULL;
address_t addr;

hint.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hint.ai_flags = 0;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

ret = getaddrinfo(address_sr.c_str(), s_port.c_str(), &hint, &serv);
//address_sr and s_port are strings with the address and port

switch (serv->ai_addr) {
    case AF_INET: {
        addr->s4 = * (sockaddr_in*) serv->ai_addr;
        //Here I want to fill the address_t struct with information
        //This line causes a segfault 
    }
    break;
    case AF_INET6: {
        addr->s6 = * (sockaddr_in6*) serv->ai_addr;
        //Conversion here
    }
    break;
```

Also, copying the memory:

```
    memcpy(&addr, serv->ai_addr, serv->ai_addrlen);
```

Causes a segfault too.

How exactly should I do this? I tried a dozen different ways and I just can't figure it out. How do I put an address from addrinfo to this union? Do I use sockaddr_storage or the sockaddr_ins?

EDIT: Editing for clarity and additional code information.

Comment: Some `memcpy()` operation instead of assignment maybe?

Comment: Maybe doing some error checking would help.  What happens if serv is null?

Answer (score 1):

You need to de-reference the pointer.

```
addr->s4 = *(sockaddr_in*) serv->ai_addr;
```

Comment: Upon launch this returns a segfault which definitely wasn't there before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not getting [getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)  right.

About the third argument, :

```
const struct addrinfo *hints
```

> The hints argument points to an addrinfo structure that specifies
>   criteria for selecting the socket address structures returned in the
>   list pointed to by res.  If hints is not NULL it points to an addrinfo
>   structure whose ai_family, ai_socktype, and ai_protocol specify
>   criteria that limit the set of socket addresses returned by
>   getaddrinfo()[...]

For example, you can ask for IPv4 address family only, and/or for datagram sockets only (which could be fine given your attempt to use UDP).
Basically, you provide an addrinfo instance, set the fields of interest, then pass a pointer to it to the function, as its third argument:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */

ret = getaddrinfo(address_sr.c_str(), s_port.c_str(), &hint, &serv);
```

In this example, the function could return not just one, but a whole list of address structures:

> The getaddrinfo() function allocates and initializes a linked list of
>   addrinfo structures, one for each network address that matches node
>   and service, subject to any restrictions imposed by hints, and returns
>   a pointer to the start of the list in res.  The items in the linked
>   list are linked by the ai_next field.

So you have to loop through the function result this way:

```
for (rp = serv; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
```

I strongly suggest to carefully read the documentation at the link I provided. There is also a long and detailed example which could alone solve your issues.

Comment: I understand how getaddrinfo works and what it returns. I am specifically asking how to properly fill address_t with the first answer from addrinfo. I read through all the Beejs Guide to Network Programming and a dozen other SO posts and while some mention the union none of them give an explicit example. So far [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846444/sockaddr-union-and-getaddrinfo/47846998#47846998) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846444/sockaddr-union-and-getaddrinfo/47846998#47846998) answer don't work as they give segfaults.

Comment: I really don't understand why you have to use that union. Even in beejs examples, the structures returned by getaddrinfo are directly used in socket/connect/bind and freeaddrinfo is called right after. No reason to copy and paste sockaddr struct around.

Comment: Because I have a UDP server and client programs and the server has multiple clients to which he constantly sends information. Since I'm doing it single-threadedly I have to store the information because I send more packets to them than I receive. Hence, the need for storing the addresses. I also think it's a glaring omission from Beejs guide. Not a single proper example of even using sockaddr_storage.

Comment: If I got you right, you don't need getaddrinfo at all, but this: http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getpeernameman.html

Answer (score 1):

`sockaddr_storage` is large enough to hold *any* `sockaddr_...` type, thus making `address_t` just as large. So, I would just `memcpy()` the entire `serv->ai_addr` in one operation and get rid of the `switch`, eg:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {};
struct addrinfo *addrs, *serv;
address_t addr;

hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
... 

ret = getaddrinfo(address_sr.c_str(), s_port.c_str(), &hint, &addrs);
if (ret == 0)
{
    for (serv = addrs; serv != NULL; serv = serv->ai_next)
    {
        memcpy(&addr, serv->ai_addr, serv->ai_addrlen);
        ...
    }
    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
}
```

Comment: This sadly causes a buffer overflow.

Comment: @m_highlanderish there is no buffer overflow in this code, as `sizeof(address_t) == sizeof(sockaddr_storage)`, and `serv->ai_addrlen` will always be `<= sizeof(sockaddr_storage)`

Answer (score 1):

Coming bit late to the party but I was also interested in using a union for the different socket address structures and found this question. I wasn't able to understand what's going wrong with addressing, type cast and segfaults because of missing a complete example, in particular what are `address_sr` and `s_port`.

So I used [Remy Lebeau's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47848141/5014688) here to code a copy and paste example to examine the situation. I found that with the union there is no type cast needed. To show how to access the members of the `address_t addr` union without segfaults I just output them to std::cout. Here is the example:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef union {
    struct sockaddr s;
    struct sockaddr_in s4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 s6;
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;
} address_t;

struct addrinfo hint{};
struct addrinfo *addrs, *serv;
address_t addr;

std::string address_sr{"example.com"}; // Resolves real IP addresses by DNS
std::string s_port{"https"};


int main() {
    hint.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    // hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP; // Already given by SOCK_DGRAM

    int ret = getaddrinfo(address_sr.c_str(), s_port.c_str(), &hint, &addrs);
    if (ret != 0) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR! " << gai_strerror(ret) << ".\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (serv = addrs; serv != NULL; serv = serv->ai_next) {
        memcpy(&addr, serv->ai_addr, serv->ai_addrlen);

        char addr_buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]{};
        switch (addr.ss.ss_family) {
        case AF_INET: {
            const char* ret = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr.s4.sin_addr, addr_buf,
                                        sizeof(addr_buf));
            if (ret == nullptr) {
                std::cerr << "ERROR! " << std::strerror(errno) << ".\n";
                return 3;
            }
            std::cout << address_sr << " AF_INET  = " << addr_buf << ":"
                      << ntohs(addr.s4.sin_port) << "\n";
        } break;

        case AF_INET6: {
            const char* ret = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &addr.s6.sin6_addr, addr_buf,
                                        sizeof(addr_buf));
            if (ret == nullptr) {
                std::cerr << "ERROR! " << std::strerror(errno) << ".\n";
                return 1;
            }
            std::cout << address_sr << " AF_INET6 = [" << addr_buf << "]:"
                      << ntohs(addr.s6.sin6_port) << "\n";
        } break;

        default:
            std::cerr << "ERROR! invalid address family " << addr.ss.ss_family << ".\n";
            return 1;
        } // switch
    } // for

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program on my test machine is:

```
example.com AF_INET6 = [2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:443
example.com AF_INET  = 93.184.216.34:443
```

I compiled it with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wdeprecated example.cpp
```